# Initial Device ID registration to Azure IoT Hub by the device itself

Tags: azure-iot-hub

In order to send messages to the Azure IoT Hub, you first need to register the devices to the IoT Hub registry, though how can you make the devices register its' ID by themselves in a safe way?

My intention of this question is about the security problem.

I am thinking of implementing them on apps such as Androids, iOS, etc. which will be used by many users.

If you give those devices a read/write permission to the registry (which the shared access key is stored in the app), there will be a risk that a malicious user finds out the shared access key and use it to abuse the system.

Are there any other solutions besides preparing a public server that provides a function to register a device and give them back the per-device access key? Or, shouldn't I use the IoT Hub and find another service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want users to be able to register their own devices with your IoT hub, you should create a separate service that can be called from the device and that returns a key. The service should register the device with IoT Hub and provide some logic that limits the number of devices that any user can register.
This is the approach taken in the MyDriving sample solution [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/campaigns/mydriving/) that allows users to register their phones as devices connected to an IoT hub.

Comment: Thanks Dominic. Guess it's the only way for IoT Hub. Otherwise, I'll just have to use the Event Hub.

Comment: @Dominic - any Github link please?

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple keys, so using the way Azure Storage works - have a primary and a secondary.

Comment: Thanks GordonB.  
You mean creating multiple Shared Access Policies? Or do you mean it by if the primary is abused, then just use the secondary or re-generate a new key?  
Anyway, it looks to me that there is going to be a lot of work.